# Play framework 2: bindfromRequest() with date field ignores time part

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm submitting some data with ajax using to my play2.1 app including a date on the form `Date.toISOString()` which gives a string on the form `2013-03-20T19:00:00.000Z`.

On the server side I use `bindFromRequest()` to bind the request data to a java object. The java object has a `Date` field. Now the date part of the field is correct in the date object, but the time part is missing. It always says midnight.

Does anyone have any experience sending dates to a play app? Is there any other approach I have not thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use something like `testDate.toUTCString()` at javascript side, it will get the time part as well.

Tested this by placing in model `public Date myDateTest;`

and in template side:

```
$(function(){

    var testDate = new Date();
    $('#myDateTest').val(testDate.toUTCString());

});
```

And corresponding field, (could be hidden as well ofc.).

```
@inputText(computerForm("myDateTest"), '_label -> "My date test")
```

At controller tested:

```
Computer comp = computerForm.get();
System.out.println("my date: " + comp.myDateTest);
```

Result was:

> Mon Mar 18 13:48:15 EET 2013

Something to be considered: if you are always catching current date you dont need to send it from template to model but instead set it at java side controller when you want it to be so, I just used current date for demonstration purposes.

Cheers.